# How to empty the bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How to empty the the bucket?

`ClearBucket` class and `clearBucket` method no longer exist. 
I need to delete the bucket and before the bucket could be deleted, it is mandatory to empty the bucket?

Comment: [Complete Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html)

Comment: Get a list of all the objects in the bucket, and iterate over them deleting each in turn

Comment: @MarkBaker Can we empty the bucket for which versioning is enabled through rest api of amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html

You have 3 options:

- if you no longer need the bucket you just delete the bucket. (you can also delete and recreate the bucket but there are no guarantees you're going to be able to recreate - ie if someone else creates a bucket with same name after you delete it you cannot use that name as bucket names are unique)
- if you still need the bucket, you list the objects in the bucket and iterate over them issuing a delete request for each object.
- if you still need the bucket, you could setup a life-cycle policy that deletes objects older than X and just wait X. S3 will kill everything in the bucket for you.